# Integrar Laravel y Mercadopago

Tags: laravel, mercadopago

Estoy intentando integrar mercadopago con laravel, pero no se como hacer para llamar desde Laravel las funciones de Mercadopago, agregue

```
use MercadoPago\Item;
use MercadoPago\MerchantOrder;
use MercadoPago\Payer;
use MercadoPago\Payment;
use MercadoPago\Preference;
use MercadoPago\SDK;
```

y luego en el codigo

```
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken("ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN");
```

pero no me reconoce Mercadopago\SDK, ya instale haciendo composer require "mercadopago/dx-php"

Alguna idea de que tengo que hacer?

Comment: Probaste sin el namespace? `SDK::setAccessToken("ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN");`

Comment: Ahi probe pero tampoco, creo que estoy haciendo algo mal o me esta faltando algo. Tengo que hacer algo previo para poder llamar con "use MercadoPago\SDK;" ?

Comment: Ahi funciono, dps de hacer composer update empezo a funcionar, gracias!

Comment: Si lo resolviste considera [escribir una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). También, aprovecha y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 2):

En Laravel 5:

```
use MercadoPago;

class MercadopagoController extends Controller
{
    protected $token;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->token = config('envtoken');
    }

    public function procesar(Request $request)
    {
        $payment = new MercadoPago\Payment();
        // Tu codigo aqui...
        $payment->save();
        return Response()->json($payment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Luego de hacer la instalación con composer me funcionó agregando la barra al inicio, de esta manera:

```
\MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken("ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN");
```